# How to have drop down list with two options, and each option changes the rows of a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So let's say I have a table like this:

| Car | Measurement method | Size | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Porsche GTR | ABC | 123 | 1231 |
| Lamborghini | ABC | 123 | 1231 |
| Honda | ABC | 213 | 41212 |
| Lamborghini | JJJ | 231 | 12124131 |
| Honda | JJJ | 2412413 | 41224112 |

So I want a drop down menu that will only show ABC methods if I choose the first option (i.e Porsche, Lamborghini ABC and Honda ABC). However, if I choose the second option, I want it to show JJJ methods for those that are available, but show ABC if JJJ not available. So it will show Porsche ABC, Lamborghini JJJ, and Honda JJJ. I need the Lamborghini JJJ and Honda JJJ removed automatically if I pick first option, and Lamborghini ABC and Honda ABC to be removed automatically if i pick second option. There should always be three rows in the same space (i.e A1 to C4). how do I do this?

Comment: With an `IF` statement? What have you tried and where is the problem?

Comment: Appreciate the table - this made replicating situation easier, however, question could be worded little better - somewhat ambiguous - e.g. "I want it to show JJJ methods for those that are available, *but* show ABC if JJJ..." - why the 'but' ? e.g. 2 "1st option i.e Porsche, Lamborghini ABC and Honda ABC. " - whilst should be clear '1st option' should refer to car - I had to read a couple of times (lost faith after encountering the 'but', so initially assumed this was error and you were really referring to 1st option = porsche,,, Below hopefully gets you closer to what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot / [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98X77buoIrj-5JsCQ?e=52jwrI) refer:

[image: Screenshot]

Key function in M4 (assuming you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel) as so:

```
=I3&" "&FILTER(D4:D8,C4:C8=I3)
```

---

**Notes:**

*Dropdown list_1 (I3):*

[image: Data validation list_1]

i.e.

```
=K4#
```

Lookup_1 (K4) generated as so:

```
=UNIQUE(C4:C8)
```

*Dropdown list_2 (I4):*

(if required, otherwise just work off the array list generated in cell M4 per first function above):

[image: Data validation list_2]

i.e.

```
= M4#
```